# Virtual Threads and Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, performance, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, virtual-threads

Recently Java 21 was released in which they added virtual threads, I was looking at some performance tests of Spring Boot on virtual threads and Spring WebFlux, the results showed that standard Spring Boot outperforms reactive Spring WebFlux, I have a question is there any point to use virtual threads in Spring WebFlux to improve performance? Will there be a performance gain? Will it not be a blocking operation? Also, how to use virtual threads in Spring WebFlux? Is my code below a good practice?

```
private final ExecutorService virtualPool;

public Mono<String> myMethod() {
    return Mono.fromFuture(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doBlockOperation(), virtualPool));
}
```

I want to use virtual threads in Spring WebFlux to get a performance boost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Virtual Threads (Project Loom) with Spring WebFlux/Reactor/Reactive libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75314973/using-virtual-threads-project-loom-with-spring-webflux-reactor-reactive-librar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work in the current `3.5.11` version of project-reactor, therefore, also in `spring-webflux` because for blocking operations you are forced to use `boundedElastic` scheduler. If you use another pool you'll get `IllegalStateException` I would expect a dedicated `Scheduler` in the next releases of the project reactor.

You can track the integration between Project Reactor and Project Loom (Virtual Thrads) under https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3084